# Dynamic array can not be input params

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mist, contract-invocation, ethereum-wallet-dapp

```
contract MyContract {
    uint public len;
    mapping(uint=>byte) public names;
    function initContracts(byte[] contractNames_){
        for(uint i=0;i<contractNames_.length;i++){
            names[i]=contractNames_[i];
        }
        len=contractNames_.length;
    }
}
```

When I use Mist, and pass [0x01,0x02,0x03], it seems that
byte[] **`contractNames_`** can not be assigned to storage mapping **`names`**, and variable `len` remains 0.

Comment: Have you tried `["0x01","0x02","0x03"]` with the hex strings quoted in Mist?  I tried your code as is and it worked with quoted hex strings in browser-solidity (output at http://pastebin.com/psYDzPn0).

Comment: thank u very much!  [0x01,0x02,0x03] is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

The input [0x01,0x02,0x03] had to **use quoted hex strings: `["0x01","0x02","0x03"]`**

The code works as is in browser-solidity and OP has confirmed it also works in Mist.